# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addLayer' of undefined - PixiOverlay

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, pixi.js

This is my code:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { PixiOverlay } from 'react-leaflet-pixi-overlay';
import { Map, TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';

class PixiOverlayClass extends PureComponent {
 render() {
  const markers = [
   {
    id: 'randomStringOrNumber',
    iconColor: 'red', // colors: https://github.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers
    position: [-37.814, 144.96332],
    popup: renderToString(<div>All good!</div>),
    onClick: () => alert('marker clicked'),
    tooltip: 'Hey!',
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    position: [-37.814, 144.96332],
    popup: 'Quack!',
    popupOpen: true, // if popup has to be open by default
    onClick: () => alert('marker clicked'),
    tooltip: 'Nice!',
  },
];
return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <Map
      preferCanvas
      maxZoom={20}
      minZoom={3}
      center={[-37.814, 144.96332]}
      // Other map props...
    >
      <TileLayer
        url="https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/rastertiles/voyager/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png"
        attribution="&copy; 
        <a href=&quot;https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright&quot;>OpenStreetMap</a> 
        contributors"
       />
      <PixiOverlay markers={markers} />
    </Map>
  </React.Fragment>
 );
}
}
export default PixiOverlayClass;
```

This is just simple code.

And I have added all the dependencies leaflet,leaflet-pixi-overlay, pixi.js,react, react-leaflet, use-leaflet

But I am still getting error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'addLayer' of undefined
    at NewClass.addTo (leaflet-src.js:6559)
    at PixiOverlay.jsx:69

It is internally calling-

```
   addTo: function (map) {
    map.addLayer(this);
    return this;
 },
```

and this is undefined.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Curiously, about the only difference I can see between your code and the demo is your's is a class-based component versus functional component. I *don't think* should cause any issue, but it appears as though `react-leaflet-pixi-overlay` uses a hook to gain access to *some* map context/reference. https://github.com/knapcio/react-leaflet-pixi-overlay/blob/master/src/PixiOverlay.jsx#L35. Perhaps there a versioning issue where the version of `react-leaflet` you have doesn't provide this context/reference.

Comment: Hi @DrewReese, upgrading **react-leaflet** worked. Thank you for the help

Comment: But It is now showing error `Cannot read property 'getContainer' of undefined
    at PixiOverlay.jsx:154
    at commitHookEffectListUnmount (react-dom.development.js:19710)` . It is internally calling `return () => pixiOverlay && pixiOverlay.utils.getContainer().removeChildren();`. @DrewReese do you have any solution for this also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading **react-leaflet**  version worked. Thank you @DrewReese

And for **Cannot read property 'getContainer' of undefined     at PixiOverlay.jsx:154     at commitHookEffectListUnmount (react-dom.development.js:19710)** this error, I passed props **zoom** to map and it worked